# Node.js- getting data from AWS DynamoDB ignoring Upeercase

Tags: android, node.js, amazon-web-services

My Node.js code gets data from DynamoDB. My android app sends a word, and Lambda scan DB looking for items which names contains that word:

```
if (typeof event.keyWord != "undefined") { 
                params.ExpressionAttributeValues[":keyWord"] = {"S": event.keyWord};

                params.FilterExpression = params.FilterExpression + " and contains (#nm, :keyWord)";
                }
```

It works fine, but is there any way to find itmes ignoring uppercases?

Comment: Dynamo db is case sensitive by default. Are you getting results which are case insensitive?

Comment: Yes, I get diffrent results. If I send word begining with capital letter it doesn't find it

Comment: There is no way around it. The data is case sensitive. Only option you have is to ensure you save the data either in all lower or all upper case. And then use the same convention whenever you query.

Comment: Is there a way that I can first get name from DB, change it whole string to lower case (if necessary), do it also with word which i sent from android and at the end compare it? If it is possible how to do it?

Comment: since you are scanning the DB, you can always remove the filter expression, and then compare the two string in Javascript. But that would mean more processing time.